# Tickspot API: Get token using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, token

I'm testing the API V2 of tickspot https://github.com/tick/tick-api but I'm having some troubles trying to get the token.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.tickspot.com/api/v2/roles.json',
    type: 'GET',
    //jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username+":"+password));
        xhr.setRequestHeader('UserAgent','Project (email@company.com)');
    }
})
.done(function(response) {
    callback(response);
})
.fail(function(response) {
    callback(response);
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

I have tried with https and http but I always receive **401 Unauthorized** and my credentials are correct.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with your subscription id in the URL? Make sure its HTTPS

All URLs start with https://www.tickspot.com/9999/api/v2/. SSL only. The path is prefixed with the subscription id and the API version.

Also V2 uses the token for authentication. You can find the token on your Tick users page.

```
Authorization: Token token=ApV99yzvwApV99yzvwApV99yzvwApV99yzvw
```

Full example

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=ApV99yzvwApV99yzvwApV99yzvwApV99yzvw" \
     -H 'User-Agent: MyCoolApp (me@example.com)' \
  https://www.tickspot.com/999999999/api/v2/projects.json
```

Comment: To get the suscription id, I have to get the access token first which is explained here https://github.com/tick/tick-api/blob/master/sections/roles.md

Comment: The token and subscription id should be on the same page. Did you find it?